# reiterating calculation of mean of group except for the observation in question for each observation in each group of a data frame

Tags: r, function, iteration, mean

Using RStudio 2022.12.0+353 "Elsbeth Geranium" Release Windows NT 10.0; Win64 & R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)

I am working on the Manifesto Project dataset and have a dataframe of 209 variables 1190 observations. The observations are grouped as per edate (election date) variable. The story is there are multiple parties taking part in each election in each country, and I need to calculate mean of some variables for each election in each country, except for the party in question. Previously I have achieved that by writing the code but now I have way too many instances so I need to reiterate and I am having problem creating this function. An excerpt of the data frame looks like below (giving only one variable - econw - subject to said calculation).

```
edate <- c("1990-03-25", "1990-03-25", "1990-03-25", "1990-03-25", "1990-03-25", "1990-03-25", "1990-03-25", "1990-03-25", "1990-04-08", "1990-04-08", "1990-04-08", "1990-04-08", "1990-04-22", "1990-04-22", "1990-04-22", "1990-04-22", "1990-04-22", "1990-04-22", "1990-04-22", "1990-04-22", "1990-05-20", "1990-05-20", "1990-05-20", "1990-05-20", "1990-05-20", "1990-05-20", "1990-05-20", "1990-05-20", "1990-05-20", "1990-05-20", "1990-05-20", "1990-05-20", "1990-05-20", "1990-05-20")
party <- c("86220", "86320", "86421", "86422", "86521", "86522", "86810", "86811", "97220", "97320", "97421", "97810", "81111", "81112", "81220", "81221", "81222", "81229", "81420", "81711", "93111", "93112", "93221", "93222", "93320", "93430", "93521", "93523", "93524", "93529", "93711", "93714", "93719", "93951")
country <- c("86", "86", "86", "86", "86", "86", "86", "86", "97", "97", "97", "97", "81", "81", "81", "81", "81", "81", "81", "81", "93", "93", "93", "93", "93", "93", "93", "93", "93", "93", "93", "93", "93", "93")
countryname <- c("Hungary", "Hungary", "Hungary", "Hungary", "Hungary", "Hungary", "Hungary", "Hungary", "Slovenia", "Slovenia", "Slovenia","Slovenia", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Romania", "Romania", "Romania", "Romania", "Romania", "Romania", "Romania", "Romania", "Romania", "Romania", "Romania", "Romania", "Romania", "Romania")
econw <- c(0.211374468421053, 0.0495444789473684, 0.0883421052631579, 0.254285829473684, 0.288283657894737, 0.0914804, 0.214830792105263, 0, 0.219519663157895, 0.167761411578947, 0.16954572631579, "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 0.554445789473684, 0.412379641578948, 0.666462765263158, 0.043414707368421, 0.0141368757894737, 1.04711717157895, 0.0240855263157895, 0.00793917526315789, 0.219133023684211, 0.040332177368421, "NA", "NA", 0.00572921631578947, "NA", "NA", 0.0320958084210526, 0.0740951968421053)
mydata <- data.frame(edate, party, country, countryname, econw)
```

So, I need to calculate the mean of econw variable in each edate group except for the observation in question. I did this previously with below code (please note this is a different - the  actual - data frame). But now I have so many instances I need to reiterate this with a function. If I am not being clear, please see below quote from the author (Wagner, 2011:852).

> This is measured by comparing the party’s salience score on the most important economic question in the survey with the mean weighted salience of all other parties in the party system.

```
econwmean_cal_1 <- c(mean(econwmean_1$econw[which(econwmean_1$econw!=econwmean_1[1,32])], na.rm = TRUE),
                     mean(econwmean_1$econw[which(econwmean_1$econw!=econwmean_1[2,32])], na.rm = TRUE),
                     mean(econwmean_1$econw[which(econwmean_1$econw!=econwmean_1[3,32])], na.rm = TRUE),
                     mean(econwmean_1$econw[which(econwmean_1$econw!=econwmean_1[4,32])], na.rm = TRUE),
                     mean(econwmean_1$econw[which(econwmean_1$econw!=econwmean_1[5,32])], na.rm = TRUE),
                     mean(econwmean_1$econw[which(econwmean_1$econw!=econwmean_1[6,32])], na.rm = TRUE),
                     mean(econwmean_1$econw[which(econwmean_1$econw!=econwmean_1[7,32])], na.rm = TRUE))
econwmean_cal_2 <- c(mean(econwmean_2$econw[which(econwmean_2$econw!=econwmean_2[1,32])], na.rm = TRUE),
                     mean(econwmean_2$econw[which(econwmean_2$econw!=econwmean_2[2,32])], na.rm = TRUE),
                     mean(econwmean_2$econw[which(econwmean_2$econw!=econwmean_2[3,32])], na.rm = TRUE),
                     mean(econwmean_2$econw[which(econwmean_2$econw!=econwmean_2[4,32])], na.rm = TRUE),
                     mean(econwmean_2$econw[which(econwmean_2$econw!=econwmean_2[5,32])], na.rm = TRUE),
                     mean(econwmean_2$econw[which(econwmean_2$econw!=econwmean_2[6,32])], na.rm = TRUE),
                     mean(econwmean_2$econw[which(econwmean_2$econw!=econwmean_2[7,32])], na.rm = TRUE))
```

However, I fail when I try to wrap this in a function. I have tried for loops, including "i" inside the mean calculation  returned problem. I tried to write my own function, again I had the problem with the reiterated index being inside the mean function. I would like to provide error messages but this is a problem I have been working for some time and then took a break from; so I really don't have the error messages at the moment.

How would I do this? I am open to any solution. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the variables `econwmean_1` and `econwmean_2`? I don't see them defined in your question.

Comment: it is the same econw variable calculated into different data frames. As described, this was the actual data frame, not the one formulated for the question.  When doing this calculation manually, I grouped each group of edate into separate data frames such as econwmean_1 econwmean_2 econwmean_3 etc. Thanks.

Comment: What you're doing is a jackknife operation.  The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68852487/r-is-there-a-tidy-method-to-get-a-jackknife-mean-for-each-group-in-a-long-data) shows a method for doing the jackknife in a dplyr pipeline.  As such, it would be easy to add a `group_by()` statement in there to focus on country-election date.

Comment: I just want to add that apparently bootstrap library has a jackknife function, for everyone who might be interested in.
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bootstrap/versions/2019.6/topics/jackknife